# How to add external function declarations inside a class C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I have the following code. I am trying to create a class that, given a server, it finds the type of server it is and then adds the correct methods of such server. So far I have a dummy class and I'm stuck here. In the `defineServer()` function, I define a macro and assign it a value, either 1 or 2. Outside in the class declaration, I then try to include them. Is there a way to fix or do this?

Server.cpp

```
class Server {
public:
    Server(int server) {
        //setServerType(getServerType());
        //defineServer(getServerType());
        this->server = server;
    }
    void defineServer() {
        if(this->server == 1) {
            #define SERVER 1
            std::cout << "SERVER_1 defined" << std::endl;
        }
        if(this->server == 2){
            #define SERVER 2
            std::cout << "SERVER_2 defined" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    #if SERVER 1
        #include "Server1.h"
        std::cout << "Server 1 added" << std::endl;
    #endif // SERVER_1
    #if SERVER 2
        #include "Server2.h"
        std::cout << "Server 2 added" << std::endl;
    #endif // SERVER_2
private:
    int server;
};
```

main function:

```
int main() {
    Server server = Server(1);
    server.defineServer();
    server.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Server1.h

```
void print() {
    std::cout << "Ye1" << std::endl;
}
```

Server2.h

```
void print(){
    std::cout << "Ye2" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Are servers implemented in the same binary module or in individual ones (`DLL`s or `.so`s )?

Comment: `#if` doesn't do what you want it to do. You need a regular `if` placed inside a `Server` member function. You also cannot include or exclude member functions at run time, so you have to design something else.

Comment: Essentially they are two slightly different objects with somewhat basic functions. I am trying to create an object that detects which object I'm dealing with to enable the right member functions for another program to use them.

Answer (score 2):

This is very bad design. You should better try subclassing the Server class, reimplementing the print() method, or just put an if-else statement into print().